# Real-time android app using webview giving slow performance and consume almost all android device ram

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, webview

I am trying to develop an android webview app which load huge amount of real-time data and live-streaming from server(from URL) , in this webview app I am facing problem of slow performance, application crash after some time due to heavy data loading, this webview eat almost all ram of android device (i check on 3 GB ram- Samsung tab-S) , please provide me solution and suggestion.

Thanks in advance...

here is the code:

```
browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //improve performance
    browser.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    browser.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    browser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
    browser.loadUrl("http://"+TotalIP+"/index.html");

    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                hdCam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) ;
                laserCam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Someting goes Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                videoLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                videoviews.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ErrorLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Put the code you have written

Comment: Well I can only suggest that you load the real time data, live streaming from server on the app itself not embedded on the webview